# jQuery .load doesnt fire if image is saved in cache (Chrome only)

Tags: jquery, image, google-chrome, jquery-load

for some reason, jQuery .load doesnt fire if image is saved in cache (Chrome only).

here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYmWQ/)

how can I fix it?

Comment: dang -- its kinda weird to see a question about a browser issue that doesn't end in "IE only"

Comment: Last I knew `.load()` didn't work in Chrome if you are running just off your file system.

Comment: 2017 and still a problem for Chrome (but not IE11, Edge, or Firefox).  Is Google falling behind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because, if current **src** and **new src** are same it doesn't load the new image as both are same. The hack for this is making the current **src** value blank.

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#tst").attr('src','');
    $("#tst").attr('src','https://www.google.co.il/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
});
```

​[jsFiddle demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/Vaishak/uYmWQ/2/)

Comment: I knew there's better way than Ohgodway's. thank you very much!

Comment: There way to do with without a hack. `.each(function(){ if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load'); });`

Comment: @NigelAngel, could you please provide a jsFiddle demo link?

Comment: @NigelAngel, thanks. 

I got what you meant. But the scenario here was like,

We are displaying an image at the first time when it loads. Then we are updating the image through server code using AJAX. Now if I have to reload the image, simply updating the "src" with same link doen't work, even if we pass a random number as query string in the URL.

As a solution, have to reset the existing "src" and reload with the same URL or to be more precise with a random number as query string.

Comment: OP reported *", jQuery .load doesnt fire if image is saved in cache"*. The code they supplied does not relate exactly to what they reported - it seems to be an attempt to demonstrate the issue. While adding a timestamp to the src will make their demonstration work, what it seems they are likely to be looking for is `if (this.complete) ... `

Comment: This didn't work for me at first (it broke IE) but combining it with part of the time-stamp fix below worked. (i.e. appending a meaningless query string at the end of the second use - an actual timestamp was not required.)  Here is what I mean:
     if (img == null) {
  img = new Image();
  img.src = 'Palette.png';

  $(img).load('Palette.png?timestamp=', function () { // mage URL is expected & required as the first parameter.
   
   context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  });
 }

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the cache by including a timestamp in the url of the image. This will cause a refresh of the cached image each time it's requested.

Comment: adding timestamp is not practical... it means I need to change the img name everytime, or there's another way to load the real img with its regular name but adding the timestamp without the need to change its name?

Comment: $('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')+'?'+Math.random());

Comment: this will really load the img every time. I want to fix it so it'll work like firefox instead of bypass it. if I wont find any better solution, I will have to use jquery.browser in order to apply this solution only for chrome

Comment: This does work & is simple if you just add a query string to the URL, per the second answer above.  In my case, the timestamp itself was unnecessary, just adding the "fake" query string was enough of a difference to make this work (i.e. a sort of hybrid of the first 2 solutions above).

Answer (score 1):

For example, you could use a timestamp:

```js
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    $("#image_test")
      .attr("src", "http://www.sandiegovips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/test-image.jpeg?timestamp="+timestamp)
      .load(function() {
             alert("image loaded!");
       });
```

```html
<img id='image_test' src=""/>
```

Comment: Yes, this approach worked for me, thank you :). e.g..if (img == null) {
  img = new Image();
  var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  img.src = 'Palette.png';

  // copy the image to the canvas
  // Fix for Chrome (uses time-stamp):
  $(img).load('Palette.png?timestamp=' + timestamp, function () { // Image URL is now expected & required as the first parameter.
   
   context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  });
 }